# gnome top panel doesn't change after using another theme

Tags: gnome, themes, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-tweak-tool, gnome-shell-extension

After a fresh Ubuntu-Gnome 14.10 install I wanted to use the [Elegance-colors theme](http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Gnome-Shell-Elegance-Colors-305966388), I installed it via apt-get and set it with tweak tool and everything seems to work but the windows top bar (don't know how it's called) keeps the default round appearance, and not the flat square from the theme. I used this theme since 12.10 I think and this is the first time that this happens.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Open the gnome-tweak-tool and under 'Appearance' tab, you will see 'Shell Theme'. Probably, that's set to 'Default'. Change it and you're done.